# Get Excel Sheet Direction with Xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

How can check the **excel sheet direction** with **python**?. my mean is *Left_to_Right* or *Right_to_Left*.

Comment: Isn't sheet direction just a display preference? Pretty sure you cannot check stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the workbook using `formatting_info` parameter like below.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("table.xls", formatting_info=True)
```

You can then use `wb.xf_list` attribute to retrieve formatting information like text_direction. Each cell in the workbook will have have an `xf_index` attribute allowing you to retrieve corresponding information in the `wb.xf_list`.

According to the [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=formatting_info#xlrd.formatting.XFAlignment), these are the possible values for the text_direction attribute.

```
0 = according to context; 1 = left-to-right; 2 = right-to-left
```